# how to add clickable buttons within fragment layouts

Tags: android, button, scrollable

in the app I am developing for my work, I am using the scrollable tab view with swipes to display a fragment on each section. Each fragment has a load of buttons to go to different websites.

For some reason the first two sections work brilliantly, however any button on the 3rd and 4th section just close the app.

I have inflated the layout in each of the fragments by having a class for each one, and in my mainpage activity it breaks on whatever button is I implement that should be on the 3rd/4th page. Any help much appreciated

The logcat -

```
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3626)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3621)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    ... 11 more
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    at com.j1mmyg88.guruapp.MainPage.onClick(MainPage.java:158)
08-04 10:24:36.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20886):    ... 14 more
```

I do not have enough reputation to add more than two links =(

Comment: What does logcat report when clicking on these 'problem' buttons? - Can you post some of your code, that handles the clicks?

Comment: Can you give us some code snippet? What you've tried.

Comment: without having enough rep it is hard for to do, as I can only post two links.